# Is construction: "I'd rather not want you to meet him again" correct?

Tags: grammar

As in title. Is construction: "I'd rather not want you to meet him again" correct? The meaning is supposed to be the same as in "I don't want you to meet him again".

Answer (score 2):

"I'd rather", short for "I would rather", is a more complex construction that it might seem at first.  It is another way of saying "I would prefer that", and would make your sentence come out as:

> "I'd rather you didn't meet him again"

There are some people who use "rather" as a verb in its own right, which would lead to

> "I rather you don't meet him again"

but this is not widespread.  There's an interesting article on this "verbal rather" [here](http://microsyntax.sites.yale.edu/verbal-rather).  Well, I found it interesting :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be technically correct, depending on what the 'rather' was intended to mean.  Because the phrases 'I'd rather' and 'I want' *can* be synonymous, that sentence *could* be read as 'I want to not want you to meet him again', which is incorrect for the intended meaning (and generally awkward).  However, the word 'rather' can simply be used for mild emphasis (as in, 'I rather like corgis').  If 'rather' was meant this way, the sentence would effectively mean 'I wouldn't want you to meet him again' (but with a certain emphasis on the speaker's not-wanting).  In that case it's perfectly correct; however, it does run the risk of confusing readers, given its other possible interpretation.

(I know this is quite old, but I thought I'd leave this response anyway for future readers.)

Comment: That would be *I rather don't want...* , instead of *I'd rather not want*. In some dialects I believe you can say *I rather you didn't meet him*, but I certainly agree that OPs construction is rather too ambiguous to use.